# isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications returns true even though I disabled it completely

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

```
if UIApplication.sharedApplication().isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications() == true {
    println("Yes, allowed")
    println(UIApplication.sharedApplication().isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications())
} else {
    //ignore
    return
}
```

When I go to settings to turn off notifications completely and then go back in the app, the app still prints `true`, allowed.

I can't seem to make it trigger false, even after an app uninstall/reinstall.

Comment: Which IOS Version you test? and have test into real device or simulator?

Comment: It's on ios8.2, ios8.3, on real devices (fresh installs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications) `isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications` will return `NO` if registration has not occurred, has failed, or has been denied by the user. `YES` will be returned if the app has registered for remote notifications and has received is device token. So in answer to your question NO it will not always return no it will also return yes if a your app has registered for remote notifications and it has received it device token.

> **Return** Value YES if the app is registered for remote notifications and
>   received its device token or NO if registration has not occurred, has
>   failed, or has been denied by the user.
>
> **Discussion** This method reflects only the successful completion of the
>   remote registration process that begins when you call the
>   registerForRemoteNotifications method. This method does not reflect
>   whether remote notifications are actually available due to
>   connectivity issues. The value returned by this method takes into
>   account the user’s preferences for receiving remote notifications.

Above point return into apple document.

**-----EDITED----------**

You can read your app's permissions using

```
UIRemoteNotificationType enabledTypes = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
```

Then performing a any operation with the different types to see which are enabled. You can also call `unregisterForRemoteNotifications` to disable notifications.

-----Changes------

> `- isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications`
>
> Returns a Boolean indicating whether the app is currently registered
>   for remote notifications.
>
> > Declaration SWIFT `func isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications() -> Bool`
> >
> > OBJECTIVE-C
> >     `- (BOOL)isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications`
>
> Return Value YES if the app is registered for remote notifications and
>   received its device token or NO if registration has not occurred, has
>   failed, or has been denied by the user.
>
> Discussion This method reflects only the successful completion of the
>   remote registration process that begins when you call the
>   registerForRemoteNotifications method. This method does not reflect
>   whether remote notifications are actually available due to
>   connectivity issues. The value returned by this method takes into
>   account the user’s preferences for receiving remote notifications.

Comment: How can I change my code so that I know when the ```user disables notification``` ?

Comment: Isn't that a deprecated method? The documentation states to use ```isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications```

Comment: `UIRemoteNotificationType` was deprecated in iOS 8, instead use the application's `currentUserNotificationSettings` `types` (which is the new `UIUserNotificationType` enum).

Answer (score 10):

I made an extension for Swift 3

```
extension UIApplication {
    func remoteNotificationsEnabled() -> Bool {
        var notificationsEnabled = false
        if let userNotificationSettings = currentUserNotificationSettings {
            notificationsEnabled = userNotificationSettings.types.contains(.alert)
        }
        return notificationsEnabled
    }
}
```

And than use it

```
UIApplication.shared.remoteNotificationsEnabled()
```

Comment: Thanks! I wrote the same code in one line: `return currentUserNotificationSettings?.types.contains(.alert) ?? false`

Comment: Why I have to enable `alert`? I can turn off alert and just let notifications show in lock screen and notification center.

Comment: There are 3 UIUserNotificationType. alert, badge and sound. I think alert is the most important permission so I check for this one only

Comment: I'd rather check if one of the three is enabled `(.alert || .badge || .sound)`

Comment: Oneliner to check if any notification enabled: `UIApplication.shared.currentUserNotificationSettings?.types.isEmpty != false`

Answer (score 8):

I have my notes about Push Notification in https://github.com/onmyway133/notes/issues/219

**Scenarios**

These are the scenarios that you can go through

`isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications` - `UIApplication.shared.currentUserNotificationSettings`

iOS 9.3.2+

- Haven't trigger push request dialog: false - none
- Enable push for app upon permission request: true - alert, badge, sound
- Turn off push for app: true - none
- Turn on push, enable only alert: true - alert
- Uninstall and install again (within 24 hours): false - none
- Deny upon asking upon permission request: true - none
- Reenable push after denial: true - alert, badge, sound

**API**

As of iOS 8+, the Push Notification API has been split to `registerForRemoteNotifications` and `registerUserNotificationSettings`.

So when you call `registerForRemoteNotifications`

- `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data)` is called
- `UIApplication.shared.isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications` returns true

It means that the app has receive the push token, and is ready to receive push notification. Whether the OS delivers push to your app depends on `user notification settings`, which is what user toggles in the `Settings`

**Show me the code**

To check if push is enabled (means that user can see the push message)

```
static var isPushNotificationEnabled: Bool {
    guard let settings = UIApplication.shared.currentUserNotificationSettings
      else {
        return false
    }

    return UIApplication.shared.isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications
      && !settings.types.isEmpty
  }
```